# How to switch a language of the form on button click in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, localization

I want to create the localized application and want to implement a language switcher (e.g. special button). I use Visual Studio 2010 express (VB.NET).

I created simple test app with one label and one button. I set form's property "Localizable" to "True" and edited components' text in 2 languages (English as default and Russian).

I know that it is needed to add

```
Imports System.Threading.Thread
Imports System.Globalization
```

at the beginning of the Form1.vb and then use

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("ru")
```

to enable Russian localization.
But if I put this line into Button_Click event it does not change the language. Is it possible to switch between languages on event like button click or combobox change?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this windows or web? VB can be used for either.

Comment: @StingyJack: It is windows app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can implement localization on Button Click event or on a change event. You can set the culture as

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("ru-RU")
```

These links will help you : [Globalizing and Localizing Windows Application](http://windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/09/29/globalization_pt2.html), [Walkthrough: Localizing Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3.aspx), [Localizing Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/z68135h5%28en-US,VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: This code does not work for me. I have added it to button click event but nothing changes after the click. (I used ru-RU in quotes, because without them it is wrong as VS states).

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is.But I have provided some useful links in my answer(edited) that may suggest a solution to your problem .

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that I want to change the language on the fly. I searched an information on this topic and have found several ways to apply localized strings to form components manually from resource files, but it is not convenient. It seems to be the best variant to apply localization settings next time the app is launched. Nevertheless, thank you for the links!

Answer (score 0):

here is a possible workaround: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/72f70870-0c0c-4eb1-886b-9db9917d080a/form-support-multilanguage-at-runtime-in-windows-based-application#8c775cc0-5e5e-4551-b5d1-52bb5c1663e8

First change CurrentUICulture, then force apply the resources of the new culture to all controls.

This code example loops through `Me.Controls`, but you should loop child containers too (panels, etc).

Doing this it changes strings, locations, sizes, etc.

```
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("es-ES")
        Dim res As ComponentResourceManager = New ComponentResourceManager(Me.GetType)
        For Each aControl As Control In Me.Controls
            res.ApplyResources(aControl, aControl.Name)
        Next
```

EDITED: You can also change thread's default culture using:

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("es-ES")
```

doing this, all new forms you create in runtime will use this new CultureInfo.