# Change the language of the native 'Pick Icon' dialog window?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi, dialog

In the (open-source) application of the screenshot below, I'm calling the [PickIconDlg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-pickicondlg) function to display a dialog window to view and select a icon:

[image]

I just would like to know if exists the possibility to change the language in which that dialog window is shown for the current running process.

I checked that [SetProcessPreferredUILanguages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setprocesspreferreduilanguages) works fine for changing the language of common file and folder dialogs, but it does not affect the 'Pick Icon' dialog.

Comment: Why not create your own dialog, load your own logos, use your preferred language?

Comment: @Aousaf rashid Thanks for comment. The reason is simple, If Windows already implemented and provides a way to show a dialog window to let the end-user see and select the icons contained in a resource file, why don't use it?. I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Also, If you search around the web, you will notice that existing open-source algorithms/libraries for .NET for the management of the icons in a resource file (in this way) is very tedious and imperfect (with bugs). I think It is much more viable to let Windows do this with just a function call to **PickIconDlg**.

Comment: You can change the thread language see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426609/how-to-switch-a-language-of-the-form-on-button-click-in-vb-net?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @nbk Thanks for comment but I was aware of the **CurrentCulture** and **CurrentUICulture** properties. It does not affect the 'Pick Icon' dialog's language.

Comment: `string newText = "New Caption"; SendMessage([Handle], WM_SETTEXT, 0, newText);`. The only problem is, these windows have all the `#32770` class name. You can catch it when it opens up with UI Automation, with an [AutomationEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automation.addautomationeventhandler), set to [WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.windowopenedevent).

Comment: Or, since you can decide what is the path shown in the `Edit` control, catch the `WindowOpened` event then check the first `Edit` child in the SubTree that has a text equal to the path you just set. The [AutomationElement.FindFirst](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.findfirst) method can be used for that,

Comment: @Jimi thanks again but you are suggesting me to enum windows with Win32 related functions or to use UI automation instead to find the dialog window, and then send the WM_SETTEXT to each label / control in the dialog to replace its text for a custom (English) text. That kind of solution really does not help me, it is too much effort just to try improve a small visual imperfection of the application (the dialog language).

Comment: That's the simplest thing that came to mind. With UI Automation you can do that easily (enough). Otherwise, you'll have to [hook it](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15553/How-to-Customize-the-PickIconDlg-with-Hook) or [build it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/colechangeicondialog-class?view=vs-2019). I don't know any other way to change the default System language. This is not a .Net managed class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to change language the 'Pick Icon' dialog, with the simple code below:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Shell32.lib")
int main(void)
{
    ULONG n;
    WCHAR s[] = L"C:\\Windows\\Explorer.exe"; 
    int i = 1;
    n = 1;
    WCHAR langs[] = L"zh-CN\0";
    BOOL ret = SetProcessPreferredUILanguages(MUI_LANGUAGE_NAME, langs, &n);
    PickIconDlg(NULL,s, wcslen(s)+1,&i);
}
```

Result:(Note that the default language on My environment is "en-US")
[image]

Seems that you need to install the Language package first. Settings > Time&Language > Language > Add a preferred language, then select the language you've added and go into Options, install the Language package.

**C# version**:

```
public enum MUIFlags : uint
{
    MUI_LANGUAGE_ID = 0x4,
    MUI_LANGUAGE_NAME = 0x8,
}

[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity, SecurityCritical]
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern bool SetProcessPreferredUILanguages(MUIFlags dwFlags, 
        string pwszLanguagesBuffer, ref uint pulNumLanguages);

    [DllImport("Shell32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern int PickIconDlg(IntPtr hwnd, string pszIconPath, 
        uint cchIconPath, ref int piIconIndex);
}
```

The languages can be set as an array of ISO names:
(The first language available in the System, in the order provided, will be used as the Dialog language).

```
string[] languages = new[] { "de-DE", "en-US", "it-IT", "es-ES", "fr-FR" };
```

Or using the **`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`** (or `CurrentUICulture`):

```
string[] languages = new[] { Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name };
```

Or using a specific culture (using **`CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture()`**):

```
string[] languages = new[] { CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US").Name };

uint numLangs = 0;
string langs = string.Join("\u0000", languages);
bool result = NativeMethods.SetProcessPreferredUILanguages(MUIFlags.MUI_LANGUAGE_NAME, 
    languages, ref numLangs);

string iconsPath = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "shell32.dll");
int selIcon = -1;
if (PickIconDlg(IntPtr.Zero, iconsPath, (uint)iconsPath.Length, ref selIcon) > 0)
{
    // selIcon is set to the selected Icon's index
}
```

**VB.Net version**:

```vb
Public Enum MUIFlags As UInteger
    MUI_LANGUAGE_ID = &H4
    MUI_LANGUAGE_NAME = &H8
End Enum

<SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity, SecurityCritical>
Friend Class NativeMethods
    <DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Friend Shared Function SetProcessPreferredUILanguages(dwFlags As MUIFlags,
        pwszLanguagesBuffer As String, ByRef pulNumLanguages As UInteger) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("Shell32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Friend Shared Function PickIconDlg(hwnd As IntPtr, pszIconPath As String, cchIconPath As UInteger, ByRef piIconIndex As Integer) As Integer
    End Function
End Class
```

```vb
Dim languages As String() = {"es-ES", "fr-FR", "en-US"}
Dim langs As String = String.Join(vbNullChar, langNames)

Dim numLangs As UInteger = 0
Dim result As Boolean = NativeMethods.SetProcessPreferredUILanguages(MUIFlags.MUI_LANGUAGE_NAME, 
    langs, numLangs)

Dim iconsPath As String = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "shell32.dll")
Dim selIcon As Integer = -1
If PickIconDlg(IntPtr.Zero, iconsPath, CUInt(iconsPath.Length), selIcon) > 0 Then
    ' selIcon is set to the selected Icon's index
End If
```

A full implementation of `SetProcessPreferredUILanguages`, `GetProcessPreferredUILanguages`, including declarations and wrapper methods, is available here:

[Can't read all the language names returned by GetProcessPreferredUILanguages function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56450144/7444103)

Comment: Yes, it does work (in comments, I assumed the OP tested it). The language is chosen from the provided languages, in the same order, based on the languages actually available in the System. Do you mind posting the equivalent C# and VB.Net versions (or I could edit your answer, if you don't mind)?.

Comment: **SetProcessPreferredUILanguages** works fine as I specified in the main post of this question, it changes for example the language of an **OpenFileDialog**, but as I also specified it does not affect the 'Pick Icon' dialog's language for me. Maybe this could be because as you mentioned the user probably needs to install the language pack, and I don't have installed it. I'll accept the answer assuming that fact will be true and once installed the lang pack it will properly replace the language for 'Pick Icon' dialog when calling **SetProcessPreferredUILanguages**. Thanks for your help.